# Transforming RGB to inputs for neural network

Tags: neural-network, algorithms

I have the RGB values from image and i want to make the neural network to recognize and see the colors like humans, is there an algorithm to train neural network with color images?

How can i make the neural network to recognize for example a blue object in more colors(orange, yellow,red,black...and so on)?

Comment: CNNs are notoriously famous for such tasks. Colors / shapes etc can be learned via convolutional layers

Comment: Search CNN for computer vision. CS231n at Standford (whose material is available openly) is good but lengthy course for the same.

Comment: How does the Dataset/Labels look?